# Make dynamic list of div elements clickable with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am creating a list of divs dynamically in JS and i want each element to be clickable by using angular. The list looks like a table fyi. This is how one list element look like.

```
var AlarmBtnTemp =
"<div ng-click='showAlarm()' >"+
    "<div>"+GetDateStringFromDateObject(alarmJson[i]["time"])+"</div>"+
    "<div>"+alarmJson[i]["name"]+"</div>"+
"</div>";
document.getElementById("AlarmBoxList").innerHTML += AlarmBtnTemp;
```

But i get that i need to compile this in a way or something since ng-click won't work otherwise.
My controller look like this

```
.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.showAlarm = function() {
        console.log("OK");
        alert("OK");
    };
});
```

This is inside a div with the Controller "AppCtrl".
So my question is, how can i fill out a list of div elements dynamically that are clickable by using angular??

Comment: Why do you need to create element like this? You can use `ngRepeat` in your view.

Comment: I would second what @Satpal said - if you're generating HTML strings behind the scenes in an Angular app, it's probably a sign you're not using Angular in the way it was intended.

Comment: I am pretty sure i am not using it in the way it is intended :P it was more or less if possible. I am not using ng-repeat since i did not find a good enough example on how to use it in my example. Since i am getting a json string from a REST api and then fills out a list based on how many elements it is and the information in the string.